# I made bubble_sort() function following the algorithm. But it is not working. where is my error?

Tags: sorting, python

This was the algorithm for bubble sort in textbook.

[image]

I tried the with WHILE loop, then I tried the same with the for loop. My answer is not sorted. Why? I follow the above algorithm in Python 3.0.

**My attempt**
[image]

Step1: I created a swap() function. it was working perfectly.
Step2: I made bubble_sort() function following the algorithm. But it is not working.
May I get help?

Comment: This is not the right place to ask for debugging your code. Anyway, you never use the result of the swap function. (As a note, you could implement `swap(a,b)` with  just `return (b,a)`, or you could avoid the function altogether since you can do `a,b=b,a`).

Comment: sorry sir. Thank you for the help. Could you suggest a free website to debug my codes? I am just a beginner. Lots of doubts coming while writing a code. I won't repeat this again.@Steven

Answer (score 1):

This one seems to be working well for me. Try out without the swap function.

[image]

Comment: Welcome COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. Please [answer well-asked questions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) instead of [off-topic ones](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).